# What is difference between Instanted then using and Uninstant using?

Tags: c#

Please looking in the below codes:

```
new StreamWriter("c:/myText.txt").Write("Some thing...");
```

And,

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("c:/myText.txt")
{
    streamWriter.Write("Some thing...");
}
```

The first code creating the file but doesn't write "Some thing..." in that.
But the second code works as well and write in that.

Why this issue happens? What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `StreamWriter` class implements `IDisposable` which means that it holds a resource that need to be released or it has some clean up code that needs to be run before the object is garbage collected.

In this case calling `Dispose` closes the stream, potentially writing the last data to the stream before doing so.

By coding `new StreamWriter("c:/myText.txt").Write("Some thing...");` you don't retain a reference to the stream and therefore have no way to call `Dispose` to properly close the stream.

Remember, the Garbage Collector **never** calls dispose for you. You must explicitly do so.

The second block of code uses the `using` statement which will automatically call `Dispose` when the block is exited. This is the correct way to write this code.

Comment: Although the GC doesn't call dispose, it *does* call the finalizer, which in many cases will call `Dispose`. It may be worth clarifying that. (I'm not sure that `StreamWriter` even *has* a finalizer, mind you...)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I did check via Reflector.NET - no finalizer. Thanks for the prompt to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The first *should* be:

```
new StreamWriter("c:/myText.txt").Write("Some thing...");
```

The second will work perfectly.  The problem with the first is that you're never closing the stream.  This will happen *eventually* (either when the program terminates, or when the garbage collector eventually finalizes the `StreamWriter`), but the first will close the file properly, as soon as the block finishes.

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake for the first one. Your answer seen that, the first code closed before it write in that but second one GC dispose and close it after write. is that true?

Comment: @ReedCopsey - The GC doesn't ever call dispose. And the first code block will **not** close the file when the block finishes. Potentially the file will remain open until the process exits.

Comment: @Enigmativity The GC doesn't call Dispose, but it does call the finalizer, which will close the file.  As I said in my answer, the first is that "you're never closing the stream" and I did explicitly mention that this will happen eventually, but that may be when the program terminates.  My answer doesn't disagree with yours.

Comment: @Enigmativity In this case, the GC will call the finalizer, which in the case of the framework's stream-based classes, will flush and close the underlying stream.  However, the timing at which this happens (or doesn't happen) is completely nondeterministic in the first case - though in a long running application, it's very likely the stream will get closed at some point due to the finalizer executing.